# Rails ransack gem to search jsonb column with key value pair as parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, jsonb, ransack

How to properly search on JSONB column, passing key & value as params.

Following this wiki https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/PostgreSQL-JSONB-searches.

Everything works for me except the bottom part, where said that we can search also by passing key value.

```
ransacker :within_json do |parent|
   Arel.sql("contacts.json_data::text") 
end
```

Like: `Contact.all.ransack("within_json_cont" => '{"key": "value"}')`
But can make it work, no result for me.

Comment: Have you added the required code in model contact.rb ?

Comment: Do you mean this: ransacker :within_json do |parent|
    Arel.sql("contacts. json_data::text")
  end
..yes

Answer (score 2):

Remove the curly braces, since it represents the complete hash. You need to get json data containe a specific key and value.

```
ransacker :within_json do |parent|
   Arel.sql("contacts.json_data::text") 
end
```

This part is correct if you are using PostgreSQL. If you are using MySQL you can do it like

```
ransacker :within_json do |parent|
   Arel.sql("contacts.json_data") 
end
```

These data is stored as text in database, so we just need to search for exact text. This can be done by

```
Contact.ransack("within_json_cont" => '"key":"value"')
```

And if you want to search for specific value for a key, you can create a ransacker

```
  ransacker :key do |parent|
    Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('->>', parent.table[:json_data],
                                    Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('$.key'))
  end
```

Hope this helps. Good luck

Comment: This looks very expensive for large data sets: does it take advantage of postgres indexing?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Yes it is expensive. First thing is you should not store large data in jsonb columns. What I usually do with jsonb columns is to store settings or data that we usually don't have to search from the application interfaces